# Lista de Tarefas

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, checkbox

É o seguinte eu estou a fazer uma lista de tarefas e neste momento estou com uma duvida queria fazer uma checkbox para quando a tarefa estiver concluida a pessoa a colocar checked a minha pergunta é se é preciso base de dados para esse efeito ou nao? de forma a que ao dar reload a pagina ele guarde a decisao da pessoa! e se for com base de dados qual a melhor forma?

```
<div class="to-do-label">
    <div class="checkbox-fade fade-in-primary">
       <input type="checkbox" id="id_do_checkbox" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa usar banco de dados para isso. Você pode guardar essa informação usando JavaScript `localStorage`.

O `localStorage` funciona semelhante a um *cookie*, que você pode usar para armazenar informações a serem usadas posteriormente, e que permanecem mesmo se o usuário fechar o navegador (mais info sobre `localStorage` [neste link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)).

Você pode criar um *listener* em jQuery para o `checkbox` que criará (ou apagará o `localStorage`):

```
$("#id_do_checkbox").on("click", function(){
   if($(this).prop("checked")){
      localStorage.marcado = true;
   }else{
      localStorage.removeItem("marcado");
   }
});
```

E fazer uma verificação se o `localStorage` existe, marcando o `checkbox` automaticamente no carregamento da página:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(localStorage.marcado){
      $("#id_do_checkbox").prop("checked", true);
   }
});
```

### Em caso de múltiplos `checkbox`

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function(){
   var box = $("input[type='checkbox']");
   if($(this).prop("checked")){
      localStorage.setItem('marcado'+box.index(this), true);
   }else{
      localStorage.removeItem("marcado"+box.index(this));
   }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   var boxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
   for(var x = 0; x < boxes.length; x++){
      if(localStorage.getItem("marcado"+x)){
         $(boxes[x]).prop("checked", true);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Incrível Obrigado novamente!!

Comment: e no caso de eu estar a listar as check box com um ciclo while visto que estou a ir buscar a informaçao a base de dados?

Comment: sim eu tenho uma checkbox para cada task

Comment: @Shider se são vários, aí complica mais... mas me dá um instante que posto uma solução na resposta.

Comment: @Shider Os checkbox estão separados por divs? Cada um dentro de uma div específica?

Comment: tem esses 2 mas por fora tem o ciclo while ou seja vai fazer essa instruçao o numero de vezes que tiver na base de dados

Comment: @Shider atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Top Obrigado e desculpe o tempo que perdeu!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70781/discussion-between-dvd-and-shider).

Comment: @Shider Valeu! Abs!